# Intercepting ajax call when ajax request goes after complete page load, also xhr interceptor and ajax start are not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, interceptor, bigcommerce

I tried xhr interceptor to modify ajax response and do some process before ajax response. My code is working earlier but now it is not. Actually I am developing app in bigcommerce, due to some change in cornerstone theme update, now my app is not working properly.
Here is the actual xhr interceptor I used:

```
var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
function onStateChange(event) {
    console.log(this.responseURL);
    this.responseText = this.response;
    //I checked url here and did some process according to it
}
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", onStateChange)
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'responseText', {
        writable: true
    });
    oldOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I also tried ajaxstart to solve this problem:

```
$(document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  console.log('started');
});
```

Ajax start function only executes for ajax request called during page load.
I want ajax start to execute after page load when I click on button. By default this button click, executes ajax request (I checked from console, it is xhr ajax) and open modal. but does not execute ajax start.

one more question, is the jquery version leads to this problem ? I used jquery 1.7.2. Not changed yet. I also tried for 1.12.4.
Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with onreadystatechange;

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return; {
          console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
       }
};
xhr.open('GET', '/your/api/endpoint/here/');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sending the request. Request is sent by other server on the store and I want to intercept it and do some process before it completes.